# How to change logo position to bottom in first page in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'm using the following code in my LaTeX Preamble:

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo2.png}\hspace*{4.75cm}~%
   \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo1.png}
    }
```

and it produces this output:

[image]

How can I put the logos closer to the bottom of the page? But still maintaining them only on the first page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Answer (score 2):

This can be as simple as adding some vertical space before the first graphic. I would recommend using `\vfill` so that LaTeX uses any available whitespace without going beyond the frame boundaries, although you can use e.g. `\vspace{1cm}` to force it further down.

```
 \titlegraphic{\vfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo2.png}\hspace*{4.75cm}~%
   \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo1.png}
    }
```

You can also insert `\vspace` at the end of your `\date{}`.